# Where is webpack serving these up?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Our company decided not to use webpack after doing a test run but we are still seeing the following screenshot in our browsers and the bundled files there are still causing issues. I dont see them anywhere on the filesystem

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Source]

Does anyone know how or where this gets generated? I've commented out all of our webpack config files even the package json but its still there any thoughts? No process is running from what I can tell either.

Comment: cmd shift . on finder to see hidden folders if you're on a mac

Comment: Are you guys using dev-server or dev-middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I just found it we still had one of the webpack generated js files left and so on pages that called that generated file, all the the import statements were then being called and grabbing the src files as well. Hopefully that made sense but I've got the issue resolved.